# Clone a part of an attributes value to another attribute in another element - js

Tags: javascript, attributes, clone

I want to [Title]
This is my wanton code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var thmbElt = document.getElementsByClassName("imgbox")[0]{var vl1 = $(this).attr("src");};
    $(.h_iframe-aparat_embed_frame).attr("src",function{
        return "https://www.example.com/video/video/embed/videohash/"+vl1.substr(51, 56)+"/vt/frame"; 
});
</script>
```

Thats result is: nothing

Comment: Is vl1 defined or undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to get src of one element and use part of it in another element. The below is the sample:

```
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg?h=350&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" 
class="imgbox" width="80px" height="80px" />
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg?h=350&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" 
class="imgbox" width="80px" height="80px" />

<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
        var thmbElt = document.getElementsByClassName("imgbox")[0];
        var thmbElt1 = document.getElementsByClassName("imgbox")[1]; //Change this line to get img src from another field

        var attr = thmbElt1.getAttribute("src"); 
        var attrSubset = "https://www.example.com/video/video/embed/videohash/" + attr.substr(8,6) + "/vt/frame";
        thmbElt.setAttribute("src", attrSubset);
    });  
</script>
```

Comment: What is the error message displayed? Can provide more details about your html and code.

Comment: Updated working code above. The first image url will be updated based on part of second image url. I have taken the sample images from internet for demonstration purpose.